# tf.summary.scalar : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to learn how to work with tensorflow summary writers :

```
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar(['logistic_loss', 'loss'],[train_logistic_loss, train_loss],
collections=[])
```

but i come with this error :

> new_name = _INVALID_TAG_CHARACTERS.sub('_', name) 
> TypeError: expected
>   string or bytes-like object

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

`tf.summary.scalar` doesn't fit to output lists of tensors. You should output them separately:

`logistic_loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('logistic_loss', train_logistic_loss)`
`loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss', train_loss)`